# Последовательное взаимодействие контролов на форме

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. На форме поставил комбобокс и за ним по горизонтали текстбокс. В комбобоксе выводится данные из сервера, а в текстбоксе из клавиатуры текст можно написать. Скажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы когда нажали на левую кнопку мыши на текстбоксе, открывалась вторая комбобокс с текстбоксом, после первым, и так продолжая. Код на C#.

Comment: Вы мечтаете о велосипеде. Познайте Tab Order.

Comment: Пол вопроса понятно, половину нет. Даже я запутался)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что Tab Order перемещает курсор на другой контрол, когда нажимаем Tab? Но вопрос другой. Так скажу, есть форма, на нем видно один текстбокс, когда кликаю на эту текстбокса, чтобы текст написать под ним открывается вторая текстбокс, которые до этого не было видно и на нем тоже можно текст написать. Итак продолжая.

Answer (score 1):

Ну разберись c `WrapPanel`. Также в коде C# напиши при нужном событии добавление в `WrapPanel` следующую коллекцию `ComboBox & TextBox`. Добавляются `WrapPanel.Items (или Children в WPF).Add(.....);`. Также пригодиться `TextBox.TextChanged += ....ComboBox.ItemsSource` для привязки к данным.